# Remove punctuations from pandas column but keep original list of lists structure

Tags: python, pandas, string, punctuation

I know how to do it for a single list in a cell but I need to keep the structure of multiple list of lists as in `[["I","need","to","remove","punctuations","."],[...],[...]]` -> `[["I","need","to","remove","punctuations"],[...],[...]]`

All methods I know turn into this -> `["I","need","to","remove","punctuations",...]`

```
data["clean_text"] = data["clean_text"].apply(lambda x: [', '.join([c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation]) for s in x])
data["clean_text"] = data["clean_text"].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
...
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your approach, I would just add a *listcomp* with a helper function :

```
import string

def clean_up(lst):
    return [[w for w in sublist if w not in string.punctuation] for sublist in lst]

data["clean_text"] = [clean_up(x) for x in data["text"]]
```

​
Output :

```
print(data) # -- with two different columns so we can see the difference

                                                                                                    text  \
0  [[I, need, to, remove, punctuations, .], [This, is, another, list, with, commas, ,, and, periods, .]]   

                                                                                     clean_text  
0  [[I, need, to, remove, punctuations], [This, is, another, list, with, commas, and, periods]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is not that big, you can try `explode` the list of list to rows then filter out the rows that contain punctuation and finally `group` the rows back.

```py
df_ = df[['clean_text']].copy()

out = (df_.assign(g1=range(len(df)))
       .explode('clean_text', ignore_index=True)
       .explode('clean_text')
       .loc[lambda d: ~d['clean_text'].isin([',', '.'])]  # remove possible punctuation
       .groupby(level=0).agg({'clean_text': list, 'g1': 'first'})
       .groupby('g1').agg({'clean_text': list}))
```

```
print(df_)

                                                   clean_text
0  [[I, need, to, remove, punctuations, .], [Play, games, .]]


print(out)

                                             clean_text
g1
0   [[I, need, to, remove, punctuations], [Play, games]]
```